# Adding three.js compound object into A-Frame causing unexpected flickering of child objects

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am adding augmented reality experience to my web app which originally created using threejs

I have a compound object(which is an Object3D instance with multiple meshes). but placing it into A-Frame giving unexpected flickering s shown in below

[image: flickering image]
 Pic of the original web app with threejs is given below
[image: three.js app]
I have the three.js code like below

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
mainObj = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(mainObj);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
renderer.sortObjects = false
container = document.getElementById("canvas-container");
width = $(container).innerWidth();
height = $(container).innerHeight();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 10, 2000);
camera.position.set(0, 67, 100);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , container);
controls.dampingFactor = 0.2;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.target.set( 0, 10, -20 );
controls.maxPolarAngle = (Math.PI/2) - 0.05;
controls.maxDistance = 800;
controls.minDistance = 2;
controls.target.set(0, buildingConfig.h/2, buildingConfig.l/-2)
controls.enableKeys = false;
controls.update();
scene.add(camera);
light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.7);
light.position.set(1, 10000, 1);
light.castShadow = true
scene.add( light );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
// logic to add child meshes to mainObj
```

*Which I changed to include in A-Frame.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  initmodels();
  AFRAME.registerComponent('e1', {
    init:function(){
      this.el.setObject3D('building', mainObj);
    }
  });
</script>

<a-scene e1>

</a-scene>
```

I guess this issue is related to the scene or renderer. Can anyone help me with a proper scene or renderer setup in A-Frame

Comment: Hmm, A-Frame will inject its own default lighting if none defined at A-Frame level unless `<a-scene light="defaultLightsEnabled: false">`....I would put the `building` in `<a-entity e1>`, not `<a-scene>`. What's the code in `initmodels`?

Comment: initmodels function creates the mainObj object which is the compound  3d model passing to A-Frame. the code is hosted at https://ar-test-svk.herokuapp.com/ and my A-Frame implementation is at https://ar-test-svk.herokuapp.com/ar.html. any suggestions  to this problem will be very helpful

Comment: Will be helpful to paste any relevant code

Comment: @sajith also it would be good if you tested this on a normal scene, not in ar.js, its way easier to debug. Also then you could say if its related to aframe, or ar.js.

Comment: @sajith has this issue been resolved ? i have been facing the same issue recently .

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. After a few trial and errors, I was able to fix it

1. Added recent version of [aframe](https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js)
2. Add `<a-scene embedded artoolkit='sourceType: webcam;' renderer='logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;'>`
3. Add `<a-marker-camera camera="far:100000; near:0.01" >`
4. Main reason was the light, Remove all lights and add only the hemisphere light into the scene and improvise upon other lights later on.

Hope this would resolve your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like z-fighting. Is the three.js version running on a different system than your aframe version?

Different platforms have different z-buffer precision. It may require you to make changes to the geometry to compensate for the limited resolution.

Also, I don't know about AR.s, but the THREE renderer has a "logarithmicDepthBuffer" option that can increase the resolution of your z-buffer at near scales, but may have some side effects.